# how to maintain the order of sql queries

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql for my project. Everything was working very fine until rapid burst of queries came into picture. On very frequent query execution order seems to be broke in my project.
My experiment was inserting 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and 9 respectively very fast and displaying them in order of their insertion time. Result, 2 and 3 interchanged their position.
I am using structure,
Insert a value 'A' in table.
Some auto id 'I' is generated in table.
Read the table for this index 'I' and insertion time.
Print the value.

In such condition how do i maintain order of elements? I can't use delimeter? I don't want to slow down my project so i am avoiding things like locking. But can use if there are no other option.
Thanks.

Comment: you can't. the optimizer randomly inserts the record at any row.

Comment: If you need records to be displayed in a particular order, use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @JW That means famous sites that are time dependent, also contain minor errors?

Comment: by term `error`, you mean what?

Comment: error means, event a occurs before b, but the website database are showing occurance of b before a.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know, among a number of very rapid transactions, that 2 and 3 are out of order?

You might be able to get around the problem, if it exists, by inserting the date using NOW(). That will be closer to capturing the sequence, even if your MySQL engine gets backed up a little bit inserting the records.

Comment: i know because i am using now() as default timestamp for their insertion and ordering them on basis of date.

Comment: Ahah! I thought you might say so. Then you already can sort by date to  get the order of the elements. You can't specify what order the records will get into the database, so the auto increment values will sometimes disagree with the order as shown by the date the record was created.